# What does and observer inside of a collapsing shell observe?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, observers

What does and observer inside of a collapsing shell observe?
Lets say we have a shell of matter collapsing to a black hole.
What would observers near the center see? How would the rest of the universe appear when,

1. The shell is approaching the Schwarzschild radius?
2. After the shell passes the Schwarzschild radius?

[Time Dilation inside a hollow shell](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229888/)
According to here you get time dialation, so what happens as the shell contracts.

Comment: Then what does observers near the center observer in their final moments? What do they observe just before/after the shell reaches them?

Comment: The thing is, that is if the Shell starts out stationary at say <2Rs, before it starts collapsing, then light should be easily overtaking it even after the shell contracts so it's inside the event horizon. So what kind of energies would those photons have from the perspective of observers near the center?