# What would an observer inside of a collapsing shell observe?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, symmetry, time-dilation, event-horizon

What does and observer inside of a collapsing shell observe? Lets say we have a shell of matter collapsing to a black hole. What would observers near the center see? How would the rest of the universe appear when,

The shell is approaching the Schwarzschild radius?

After the shell passes the Schwarzschild radius?

Time Dilation inside a hollow shell According to [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229888/) you get time dialation, so what happens as the shell contracts.

Comment: Related, but not exactly a duplicate, [A Hollow Black Hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69821/a-hollow-black-hole).